# Algorithm to find Max number of Customers

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to solve the following problem in a more efficient manner than brute force.

Problem:
Write a program for a company that wants to serve as many customers as possible. The company has `n` types of products. There is an arbitrary number of units for each type of product (you are given this data). The company also has `c` number of customers. Each customer orders some number of units of every product type (can be zero). In order to *serve* a customer, you must send them all the requested units for every type of product. We want to find the maximum number of customers that can be served.

Example Input data:

| Product Type | Total Units Available | Customer 1 | Customer 2 | Customer 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type A | 50 | 30 | 50 | 0 |
| Type B | 100 | 0 | 100 | 10 |

In the above example the maximum number of customers we can serve is 2:

- Send *Customer 1* 30 units of Type A and 0 units of Type B.
- Send *Customer 3* 0 units of Type A and 10 units of Type B.

Note that if we serve *Customer 2* we will use up all units of both types and cannot serve another customer.

I have tried writing a brute force solution, which tests every possible combination of customers. However, this approach takes too long to execute even with a smaller number of customers and product types. Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Brute force Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
 
def findsubsets(s, n):
    return list(itertools.combinations(s, n))
 
df = pd.read_excel('file.xls')

s = df.columns[4:-1]
l = len(s)

stock = df['Available Stock'][:-1]
max_fulfil = 0
ans = []
for i in range(l, -1, -1):
  combs = findsubsets(s, i)
  print(i)
  for comb in combs:
    # print(comb)
    order_stock = None
    for c in comb:
      if order_stock is None:
        order_stock = df[c][:-1].copy(deep=True)
      else:
        order_stock += df[c][:-1]
    if (sum(order_stock>stock) ==  0):
        max_fulfil = i
        ans.append()
  if max_fulfil != 0:
    break
print(ans)
print(max_fulfil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using [ortools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) (install it using `pip install ortools`):

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

import pandas as pd


# Data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "Product Type": ["Type A", "Type B"],
    "Total Units Available": [50, 100],
    "Customer 1": [30, 0],
    "Customer 2": [50, 100],
    "Customer 3": [0, 10],
})

# Model
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Variables
C = [model.NewBoolVar(col) for col in data.columns[2:]]

# Constraints
for _, row in data.iterrows():
    _ = model.AddLinearConstraint(
        cp_model.LinearExpr.Sum([
            C[i] * row[f'Customer {i + 1}']
            for i in range(len(data.columns[2:]))
        ]),
        0,
        row['Total Units Available'],
    )

# Objective
model.Maximize(cp_model.LinearExpr.Sum(C))

# Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

# Print solution
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    print("Optimal solution found!")
    print(f"N. of customers served: {int(solver.ObjectiveValue())}")
    print(f"Customers served: {[c.Name() for c in C if solver.BooleanValue(c)]}")
```

This is the output:

```
Optimal solution found!
N. of customers served: 2
Customers served: ['Customer 1', 'Customer 3']
```

Comment: Nice approach.  Multidimensional knapsack could be more appropriate for this problem (https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/algorithms/pywrapknapsack_solver)

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a better way than brute force. This kind of classical computational problems is solved with [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking):

> Backtracking is a class of algorithms for finding solutions to some computational problems, notably constraint satisfaction problems, that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons a candidate ("backtracks") as soon as it determines that the candidate cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution.

Short description of the method from Wikipedia:

> The backtracking algorithm enumerates a set of *partial candidates* that, in principle, could be *completed* in various ways to give all the possible solutions to the given problem. The completion is done incrementally, by a sequence of *candidate extension steps*.

The article has also some pseudo code and examples as a start. It is worth learning this method, because it solves a lot of optimization problems in a very fast way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be expressed as a [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem. With python you can try with [scipy.optimize.linprog.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) or with [PULP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/). Later allows you to export your problem to external solvers that are optimised for hard problems of this nature.

Edit:
To be exact, problem can be expressed as binary integer programming (BIP) and both mention tools allows you to restrict solutions to integers.

---

Sketch on how to express as linprog

Looking at equations at [scipy.optimize.linprog.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) we have
`x` that is `1` when customer is chosen and `0` if not.  For his reason we have `l=0` and `u=1` from 0 <= x <= 1 from last equation and `x` is from set of integers.
`bub` is Total Units Available  column and `Aub` is matrix of customers. This way expression `Aub * x` returns vector on how much of each units is requred and that is limited by `bub`.
`Aeq` and `beq` is all zeros as we dont have exact constraints. This makes me question efficiency of this approach.

We want to maximise this by sum over `x` so `c` becomes vector of `1` or `-1`  when problem is to be expressed around minimisation.

Answer (score 0):

That is typically a job for a branch&bound approach.

Branch & bound, in first approach, is just a way to test all combination. But doing it recursively, using idea that, "there are 2 kind of combination: those in which we find customer 1, and those in which we don't find them". And then, recursively, each of those group can also be split in 2: "those that have customer 2, and those that haven't". Etc.

So, if you have 20 customers, you have 2 categories, and then 2 subcategories in each of those 2 categories, that is 4 subcategories, and then, among those... ending up with 2²⁰=1048576 subcategories.

So, it is just a way to say that there are 2²⁰ case to check, as you did.
But then, because of the way we enumerate recursively those 1048576 cases in a tree on categories and subcategories, it becomes possible to be smarter than that

Let's just start with a recursive algorithm to enumerate all cases

```py
import numpy as np

NART=3
NCUST=20
maxi=np.random.randint(50, 100, (NART,))
customers = np.random.randint(0, 50, (NART,NCUST))


def bb(rest, customers, i, lst):
    if i>=NCUST:
        if (rest>=0).all():
            return lst
        else:
            return []

    lstWithoutI = bb(rest, customers, i+1, lst)

    restWithI=rest-customers[:,i]
    lstWithI = bb(restWithI, customers, i+1, lst+[i])
    
    if len(lstWithoutI)>len(lstWithI):
        return lstWithoutI
    else:
        return lstWithI
```

So, as is, it is just an algorithm that test 2ᴺᶜᵁᔆᵀ combinations, but does it recursively.

But now, we can start to be smarter, and cut whole "branches" of the trees of 1048576 solutions without exploring them.

For example, clearly, if combining customer 1 and 2 already exceeds stock, then, there is no need to explore all the 262144 combinations that have customer 1 and 2 (and 3 or not 3, and 4, or not 4, etc.)

So, we can transform our algorithm like this

```py
def bb(rest, customers, i, lst):
    if i>=NCUST:
        return lst

    lstWithoutI = bb(rest, customers, i+1, lst)

    restWithI=rest-customers[:,i]
    if (restWithI>=0).all():
        lstWithI = bb(restWithI, customers, i+1, lst+[i])
        if len(lstWithI)>len(lstWithoutI):
            return lstWithI
    return lstWithoutI
```

So, we explore a branch only if the beginning of the branch is ok (and then, no need to check if it is ok when reached the leaf, since by construction, we are always OK).

So, doing so, we explore way less that 1048576 combination. In one run (since my data are random, that is random also, of cours), for example, I've explored only 268 combinations over the 1048576 possible ones. And 4344 partial combinations over 2097152 (that is node in the tree. And you probably know that if there are 1048576 leaves, there are 2097152 nodes). So, as is, it is a already a quite efficient way to enumerate all possibilities.

But we can cut even more:
For example, if we have already found a solution implying 6 different customers, then, when exploring combinations with customer 1, 8 and 10, and some others after customer 18, then, we can stop exploration here, without trying to find better from here. Because, we know in advance that even if we include all the remaining customer in our partial solution, we can't beat 6.

So, that gives

```py
def bb(rest, customers, i, lst, bestSoFar=-1):
    if i>=NCUST:
        return lst
    # No need to explore if we already found better than the best possible solution from here
    if len(lst)+(NCUST-i)<=bestSoFar:
        return []
    lstWithoutI = bb(rest, customers, i+1, lst)

    restWithI=rest-customers[:,i]
    if (restWithI>=0).all():
        lstWithI = bb(restWithI, customers, i+1, lst+[i])
        if len(lstWithI)>len(lstWithoutI):
            return lstWithI
    return lstWithoutI
```

So (with same seed of course), using this new reason to cut exploration, we explore only 143 combinations, and 268 partial solutions (that fact that it is the same number of the number of full combinations explored before is just coincidence).

That is still almost brute force. I mean, it is a comprehensive enumeration of all possibilities, and selecting the best one. But in a way that spare exploration of whole group of possibilities, because we are sure that either there is no solution in them, or no solution better than the one we already know.

And then, from there, we can even start to be smarter, and add an heuristic.
That is, instead of trying customers in order (customer 1, then customer 2, ...), we can try first the one that are more likely to be part of a good solutions. That try in priority the customers that require less of the rare resources.

Which allows

- Even better "cutting" of branches, since the faster in the exploration we reach good solutions, the more the "no need to explore solution that can't do better" cutting will cut branches.
- And even to decide arbitrarily to stop exploration after a while, this time, not because we are 100 % sure that we can't miss better solution, but because we are 99% sure that the best solution is among the first one we explore (but if we do that, it stops to be a comprehensive exploration of all possibilities, and becomes an estimation of the best solution). Still, that is what you would do if you had millions of customers. And With millions of customers, such an heuristic could allow to explore only a ridiculous fraction of all possibilities while being 99.9999% sure that the best solution is among them.

Note that I am pretty sure that (probably without heuristic) this is what `ortools`, proposed by Ricardo does. I am only here describing a very very classical method to solve such problems (that is the "fallback" method. Where there are polynomial solutions, of course, they must be preferred. But when we feel that an exploration of combinations, therefore exponential cost, is the only way, at least without heuristic, then, that is the way to do this combinatorics exploration that always work, and that allows to cut whole branches as I described; plus, that make quite easy to plug some heuristic in between.
So, I just wanted to describe the algorithm rather than a library solution. But pragmatically, it is of course probably better to rely on a library that have already implemented this.